# How do I print the name of the file using Resharper File Templates?

Tags: resharper

I am getting around to creating some custom file templates using R# (Ultimate v9.2) from within VS 2013. I simply want to print the name of the file at the top of the document. I read that all I should need to do is use **$NAME$** in the template so that the filename I used to create the file with overlays the placeholder no problem.

Here's a link to the support page for the Template Editor:
https://www.jetbrains.com/resharper/help/Reference__Template_Editor.html?search=file%20template

And here's a link to the 'latest' how to choose a macro support page:
https://www.jetbrains.com/resharper/help/Reference__Choose_Macro.html

And then here's a link to the blog for creating new macros...in which most other links to helpful information are dead:
http://blog.jetbrains.com/dotnet/2010/10/14/templates-galore-extending-functionality-with-macros/

thanks for any additional insight that jetbrains is unable to publish.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For [template parameters](https://www.jetbrains.com/resharper/help/Templates__Template_Basics__Template_Variables.html) (syntax: `$PARAM_NAME$`), you can choose for example the [*macro*](https://www.jetbrains.com/resharper/help/Templates__Template_Basics__Template_Macros.html) "Current file name" or "Current file name without extension".

This would be an example for a C# class file template:

[image: Template Screenshot]

Comment: would the same rules apply for any file type...such as .js?

Comment: Main difference I'm seeing is the inability to select any kind of macro from any dialog that I've found available. Maybe that's what is going on...no macros are being processed when the template is executed so the ${NAME} remains just that...a string

Comment: Please use `$NAME$`, not `${NAME}`

Comment: what that does is add a variable to the template so that AFTER the file is created $NAME$ is highlighted and I can type into it and every where $NAME$ may be is replaced...what I am attempting to do is per the name of the file I entered when creating the file have that immediately available in the source document...in R# docs, they say ${NAME} or even just $NAME should work for this.

Comment: You have to assign a *macro* to the parameter (like in screenshot in my answer). Click on "Choose macro". Where did you find `${NAME}` in the R# docs? (I've added links to the docs in my answer.)

Comment: ok...so my misunderstanding is that once I create a variable I can THEN assign a macro to that variable...now the only problem is they don't have a predefined macro for printing the file name...silly

Comment: did some lengthy updates to the question to better define what the real problem is w/ more links

Comment: the other thing to point out was that you have to select 'All macros' in the choose macro window because, for whatever reason, it's not listed in the 'suitable...' list